# javascript class and object

Tags: javascript

Can this be done in Javascript? I am converting a java wiki page to javascript. I'm pretty sure var should be used instead of int right?

```
class Sample extends Object {

 int ivar1;
 int ivar2; 

Sample(int i, int j) {
 ivar1 = i;
 ivar2 = j;

}

int emptyMethod() {}
...

for (int i = 0; i < maxLoops; i++) {
...
 }
}
```

Comment: What is `for` in? In a method? Outside the class definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Sample(i, j) {
    this.ivar1 = i;
    this.ivar2 = j;

    this.emptyMethod = function() {};
}

var sample = new Sample(1, 2);

sample.ivar1; // 1
```

Comment: the method should be defined on a prototype, probably. There is no need to have private copy for each instance.

Answer (score 2):

Try taking a look into either **[prototypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)** or **[closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)**.

From [MDN (prototypes)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype):

> All objects in JavaScript are descended from Object; all objects
>   inherit methods and properties from Object.prototype Object.prototype,
>   **although they may be overridden** (except an Object with a null
>   prototype, i.e. Object.create(null)). For example, **other constructors'
>   prototypes override the constructor property and provide their own**
>   toString methods. Changes to the Object prototype object are
>   propagated to all objects unless the properties and methods subject to
>   those changes are overridden further along the prototype chain.

Many agree that changing the `Object` type directly can cause issues, especially when linking in other libraries. Becasue of this, it's usually best to use closures.

From [MDN (closures):](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

> Languages such as Java provide the ability to declare methods private,
>   meaning that they can only be called by other methods in the same
>   class.
>
> **JavaScript does not provide a native way of doing this**, but it is
>   possible to **emulate private methods using closures.** Private methods
>   aren't just useful for restricting access to code: they also **provide a
>   powerful way of managing your global namespace, keeping non-essential
>   methods from cluttering up the public interface to your code.**

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to loosly mimmick this behavoir. There are several libraries avaiable to help you build more object oriented javascript like:

- Prototype.js
- Backbone.js
- Angular.js

Using `Prototypes` in a loose example (not the prototype framework):

```
function Sample() {};
var i = new Sample();
var x = new Sample();    

Sample.prototype.init = function() {
    this.ivarA = "constant 1";
    this.ivarB = "constant 2";
}
Sample.prototype.set = function(i, j) {
    this.ivar1 = i;
    this.ivar1 = j;
}

//example of override
m.set = function(i, j) {
    this.ivar1 = i + j;
    this.ivar2 = i + i + j;    
}

i.init();
i.set("hey", "whats up?");
x.set(10, 5);
```

Comment: The `init` function doesn't actually do anything, nor is it necessary.

Comment: @Shmiddty yea, I just whipped up an example quick, made edit to add a little more context.

Answer (score 1):

```
// class Sample ...
// (including constructor)
function Sample (i, j) {

  this.ivar1 = i;
  this.ivar2 = j;

}

// ... extends Object
Sample.prototype = Object.create(Object.prototype);
// (the first Object is part of call, the second Object is the one from 'extend')

Sample.prototype.emptyMethod = function () {};
...

// Don't know where to put, probably error in original question:
// for (var i = 0; i < maxLoops; i++) {
// ...
```